# How to correctly write a C# helper class to read multiple integers from single line?

Tags: java, c#

I'm trying to switch from Java to C# and am also practicing competitive programming problems, but what I found that C# doesn't have a convenient way to read a single int from the console like `Scanner.nextInt()`. Now to be fair I don't use that approach in Java either, but a helper class instead that does something like this:

(This is a static inner class):

```
static class InputReader {
    public String[] input;
    public BufferedReader reader;
    ublic int current;

    public InputReader(InputStream stream) {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream), 32768);
        input = null;
        current = 0;
    }

    public String next() {
    while (input == null || current == input.length) {
        try {
            current = 0;
            input = reader.readLine().split("\\s");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

        return input[current++];
    }

    public int nextInt() {
        return Integer.parseInt(next());
    }
}
```

I tried rewriting the same in C# and it came out like this:

```
internal static class InputHelper
{
    private static int current;
    private static string[] buffer;

    public static string next()
    {
        while (buffer == null || current == buffer.Length)
        {
            current = 0;
            buffer = Console.ReadLine()?.Split();
        }

        return buffer[current++];
    }

    public static int NextInt()
    {
        return int.Parse(next());
    }
}
```

However when I pasted in this sequence from a problem statement, I got an exception (NumberFormatException):

```
3
5 1
3
3 3
1 2 3
4 1
1
```

EDIT: My suspicion is that it throws an exception because of the different line breaks used on windows linux, but this could be totally wrong.

And other times for example:

```
var n = InputHelper.NextInt();
while (n > 0)
{
    n--;
    Console.WriteLine(InputHelper.NextInt());
}
```

It works just fine. Any ideas as to why it could be wrong?

Comment: NumberFormatException is a java exception, to which code do you refeer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why yours doesn't work, but you could try this instead:

```
public static class ConsoleHelper
{
    private static string[] input = new string[0];
    private static int inputIndex;

    public static void ReadNextInput()
    {
        input = Console.ReadLine().Split();
        inputIndex = 0;
    }
    public static int GetNextInt()
    {
        return int.Parse(ReadNextWord());
    }
    public static string GetNextWord()
    {
        return ReadNextWord();
    }

    private static string ReadNextWord()
    {
        if (inputIndex >= input.Length)
        {
            ReadNextInput();
        }

        return input[inputIndex++];
    }
}
```

I've been using this in competitions, and up till now, have never failed me.

EDIT:

You could try this split: `Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`
This automatically removes empty elements in the output array.

Comment: `Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` did the job! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> However when I pasted in this sequence from a problem statement, I got an exception (NumberFormatException).

I suspect this is because of trailing spaces on the input.  By default, `Split` will emit an empty entry when it encounters a delimiter that isn't *followed by a non-delimiter*.

For example, given the input `1  2` (with two spaces), the result would be `["1", "", "2"]` because the first space is followed by another delimiter.  Similarly, the input `1 2`  (with a trailing space) would yield `["1", "2", ""]`, because the final delimiter has nothing to its right.

This is often a point of confusion, and the documentation for `Split` doesn't do a great job of informing you:

> **Returns:** An array whose elements contain the substrings in this instance that are delimited by **one or more characters in `separator`**. *[emphasis mine]*

To me, that phrasing implies that contiguous delimiters would be 'flattened' into one, but that's not how it works at all.

To avoid this behavior, use an overload of `String.Split` that accepts `StringSplitOptions`, and specify `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.